# cant find standard controller that is a custom class from a managed package

Tags: managed-package, controller, class, custom, object

I have a VF page that calls a custom object from a managed package as a controller, so, I am seeing something like this:
 < apex:page standardController="mlk_MarksCustomObject__c" >

I cannot find the custom object anywhere, when I go to apex classes, there is nothing there, I am checking the mlk namespace as well as checking as if there was no namespace, tried same thing in Developer console, don't see any class called mlk_MarksCustomObject__c

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

There is no class for it, its a standard controller not a custom controller. Just like if you put `standardController="Account"` there doesn't need to be an Account class.

**[Standard controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std.htm)**

> The Force.com platform provides a number of standard controllers that
>   contain the same functionality and logic that are used for standard
>   Salesforce pages. For example, if you use the standard Accounts
>   controller, clicking a Save button in a Visualforce page results in
>   the same behavior as clicking Save on a standard Account edit page.